# How to style a global elements using material ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need to style `*, *:after, *:before` using `material ui`, also I need to change the global font-family of the web app. How do i achieve this?

Material-UI Version: **1.0.0-beta.5**

React Version: **15.4.1**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the longest time this was one of those hidden options in Material-UI, but now the easiest way to style any element in the DOM is to use the @global class provided by jss-plugin-global:

```
const GlobalCss = withStyles({
    "@global": {
      "html, body": {
        margin: 0,
        padding: 0
      },
      ".App": {
        backgroundColor: "blue",
        fontFamily: "sans-serif",
        textAlign: "center"
      }
    }
  })(() => null);
```

Here's a [CodeSandbox project](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-darkness-3kllh?file=/src/App.js) as an example, using this method replacing the usual css file.

This feature is referenced here in the [docs](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#global-css-override)

Update: MUI v5 has a dedicated component for global styles, but works the same way:

```
import { GlobalStyles } from '@mui/material'

...

  const globalStyle = {
    a: {
      textDecoration: 'none'
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <GlobalStyles styles={globalStyle} />
      <App />
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Write your global css rule in a separate file.
2. In your project, find out the entry html file named like `index.html` or maybe other name.
3. add `css link` links to the file of step1 in that html file as normal html file do.

Answer (score 1):

fontFamily is a property of theme. You need to pass down the propertys with a "MuiThemeProvider" wrapper.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({  
  palette : {
    primary: {  
      light:  '#fff8e1',
      main: '#fff8e1',
      dark:  '#fff8e1',
    },
  }, 
  typography: {
    useNextVariants: true,
    fontFamily : 'Poppins',
    fontSize : 12,
  },
});


<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <CssBaseline />
  <React.Fragment>
    <Typography variant='h4'>
    </Typography>
  </React.Fragment>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

[API < MuiThemeProvider>](https://material-ui.com/api/mui-theme-provider/)

[API Themes](https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/#themes)